How to change color of dynamic title in power bi
means lets take an example there is statement in power bi card -- Top risk around security issue and management issue . and this security issue and management issue are coming from measure and this we concatenate with top risk around
but i want this security issue and management issue part will highlight with different color than top risk around.

You question is unclear. Try editing it to provide more clarity on your ask/question. Consider adding screenshots or visuals to help explain what you are after.
